# JS libraries for heavy HTML DOM handling

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

I'm building a small sticky notes app with html, css and Javascript. The contents of these sticky notes are not just plain text. They can have inner tags like `<p>, <span>, <img>` etc...

So when a user selects some content in the DIV of the sticky note ( which is set to contenteditable = true ), and clicks on a button, say 'Make text bold', The selected content should be changed to Bold text.

I'm using JavaScript's Range object for selection. But the problem is replacing the existing nodes and content with the newly formatted ones is very complex. Say for scneraio...

**Sample html :**

```
<p>
This is some paragraph <b> in bold </b>
<span>This is some span</span>
</p>
```

And lets say the user selects from

```
<p>
This is <SELECTION-START>some paragraph <b> in bold </b>
<span>This is some<SELECTION-END> span</span>
</p>
```

So the selection-start starts from half of the `<p>` tag, it has the `<b>` tag completely. And ends halfway in the `<span>` tag. Using the Range JS object and manipulating nodes in the DOM seems little tough to achieve this.

My question is,

- Is there any existing libs that apply formatings and other stuff to HTML dom selections ?
- If not please point to some code which achieves this function.

Thanks..

Note : I don't want any HTML editors or plugins. Just a 'DOM editting lib' or 'code for easy DOM handling'

Answer (score 1):

My [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library does some of this. See the [class applier module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule), for example.

There is also built-in browser support for styles such as boldness, although you don't have total control over the mark-up it produces. The method you need is [`document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand). For toggling boldness, use

```
document.execCommand("Bold", false, null);
```